# Progress bar loading message doesn't show in JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

The Loading message in JQuery Mobile 1.1.0 doesn't seem to be working. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2ktR/) for the code.

When I use version 1.0b2, it works as expected. Is this a bug in 1.1.0?

Answer (score 2):

It is not a bug. Latest Jquery supports more config options. You can define the laoding message theme etc.

[Refer the documentation here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html)

Sample code

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.loadingMessageTheme = 'a';
    $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
});
```

Save above mentioned code in a js file (e.g. config.js ) and import it before importing jquerymobile framwork.

Good luck.